# Get IP Address from 32bit number

Tags: ruby, csv, ip

In ruby, How to get 32 bit number for an IP address. Its used in IpTOCountry.csv

e.g. 
1.2.3.4 = 4 + (3 * 256) + (2 * 256 * 256) + (1 * 256 * 256 * 256)
is 4 + 768 + 13,1072 + 16,777,216 = 16,909,060

So if I have 16,909,060. How can I get "1.2.3.4". I can only use standard ruby libraries.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`IPAddr`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html) class:

```
require "ipaddr"
IPAddr.new("1.2.3.4").to_i
# => 16909060
```

The other way round:

```
ip = IPAddr.new(16909060, Socket::AF_INET)
# => #<IPAddr: IPv4:1.2.3.4/255.255.255.255>
ip.to_s
# => "1.2.3.4"
```